# How to call all php functions in array

Tags: php, arrays, function

If I have a array named myFunctions, contains php function names like this...

```
$myFunctions= array("functionA", "functionB", "functionC", "functionD",....."functionZ");
```

How can I call all of that functions using that array?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

> PHP supports the concept of variable functions. This means that if a variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

```
foreach($myFunctions as $func) {
    $func();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
foreach($myFunctions as $myFunction) {
    call_user_func($myFunction);
}
```

or

```
array_walk($myFunctions,'call_user_func');
```